# JQuery to load external pages in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to load external pages in index.html Menu links have function -
About

```
function about() {jQuery('#container').load('about.html');}
```

I am using jquery function on each child page to get the data from xml. Apparently, wen I call the jquery just once on index.html and use same for child it works differently. When I single click it empty the `#container` but doesnt external file data. But when I double click on menu tab then i see the data. I am really lost and need help to figure out as wat m doing wrong.
hashworld.com.au/test/test.html I have uploaded code here please have a look

Comment: how and where do you call about() function? can you post some code in a fiddle?

Comment: We need to see more of your code. What's in the XML file? What are your click events on the menu? Are the paths to your html files correct in the load function?

Comment: Index Page has a menu link - 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="about();">About</a> and i have defined function as - 
function about() {jQuery('#container').load('about.html');} which loads the about.html in container id of same index.html page. it works fine if I call jquery on each child page but if remove from child page and call only once in index.html it doesnt work same. I had to click twice to see the results.

Comment: You will see it load content only if we click test link twice. Please suggest..   http://hashworld.com.au/test/test.html

Comment: @user1185158 - the link you provided goes no where or is invalid howver and should be: http://www.hashworld.com.au/test/test.html

Comment: your script tags should ALWAYS HAVE `type="text/javascript"` in them

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss That's not entirely true. This attribute is only required in XHTML, otherwise this attribute is optional (if you're using XHTML then additionally all special characters should be encoded or all content should be wrapped inside a CDATA section if you want your code to be validated correctly). Since Netscape 2, the default programming language in all browsers has been JavaScript.

Comment: @MMM - and his document referenced IS xhtml so it does appear to apply here and is safe to add in any case.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I know it is XHTML, but I just wanted to clarify that you don't always have to have `type`.

Answer (score 0):

In rules.html try to change this:

```
<script src="js/xmlConfig.js"></script>
<script>
    function parseXml(xml){
        $(xml).find("rules").each(function(){
        $(xml).find("rule").each(function(){
            var rule = $(this).text();
            $('<li></li>').html(rule).appendTo('.content ul');
        });
      });
    }
</script>
```

...into this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "xml/global_webconfig.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
  });

  function parseXml(xml){
        $(xml).find("rules").each(function(){
        $(xml).find("rule").each(function(){
            var rule = $(this).text();
            $('<li></li>').html(rule).appendTo('.content ul');
        });
      });
  }

});

</script>
```

Comment: Yes I have updated same page and it works fine now. Woohoo!! But I 10 more pages that uses same xml and I dont want to load xml again and again. Can you tell how to load xml script once on index page. Please see the www.hashworld.com/test/test.html as I have updated the page

Comment: I am using same xml for other pages and want to advoid loading xml again and again for all pages. Can you advice as how to call it only 1 time on main page and same xml for child pages that loads on clicking menu tabs. www.hashworld.com/test/test.html

Comment: Your initial question has been answered, so you should create new question... That way you'll have more chances to get answer; as more people will see it....

Comment: I have many pages that loads in main page div on click and all are reading same xml. Can you please tell me how to call xml once on main page so I can use it for all child page?